# Attempt to fix hard disk with errors on a Linux Live CD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I've tried to fix an HP Laptop (`HP Pavilion x360 Convertible/8074, BIOS F.35 08/20/2015`) that doesn't boot (`OS not found`), with a Proteus Linux live USB.

Here is what I have attempted.

`fdisk -l` didn't show the hard disk.

`lsblk` shows the hard disk properly (`sdb`):

```
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 465.2G  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0   585M  0 part
```

`mount` shows several errors:

```
root@porteus:~# mount -o ro -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/windows
Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
```

`ntfsfix` shows several errors as well:

```
root@porteus:~# ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Failed to sync device /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Failed to sync device /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

`parted` shows errors too:

```
root@porteus:/home/guest/Downloads/testdisk-7.1# parted -l
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? retry
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? ignore                                                      
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb2: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? ignore                                                      
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? retry
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? ignore                                                      
Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPVX-6 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

`testdisk` didn't work, but after running it, `lsblk` stopped working as well, and didn't list the `sdb` drive; however `/dev/sdb` still exists as a file.

Here's part of the `dmesg` log, when `lsblk` stopped seeing the hard disk.

```
[ 2073.836517] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2073.836550] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2073.836587] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2073.836620] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1, async page read
[ 2077.982908] scsi_io_completion_action: 19 callbacks suppressed
[ 2077.982937] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[ 2077.982961] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 2077.982979] print_req_error: 19 callbacks suppressed
[ 2077.982986] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 flags 801
[ 2078.802774] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[ 2078.802790] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 2078.803407] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[ 2078.803420] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 2078.803584] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 2078.803597] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 2078.804473] sdb: detected capacity change from 500107862016 to 0
[ 2078.808309] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[ 2078.808313] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 2078.808362] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[ 2078.808365] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 2078.852653] udevd[1594]: inotify_add_watch(5, /dev/sdb2, 10) failed: No such file or directory
[ 2078.856948] udevd[1595]: inotify_add_watch(5, /dev/sdb1, 10) failed: No such file or directory
```

Here is more of the `dmesg` output.

```
[    6.378155] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   11.058196] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   16.410158] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   18.074175] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   18.125056] ata1.00: ATA-9: WDC WD5000LPVX-60V0TT0, 01.01A01, max UDMA/133
[   18.125071] ata1.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[   18.126131] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   18.137197] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD5000LPVX-6 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   18.139002] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[   18.139015] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[   18.139111] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   18.139123] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[   18.139285] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   18.147088]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[   18.148767] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
...
[   34.611396] ata1.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying PIO
[   34.611414] ata1: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
[   34.611438] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x2 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[   34.611446] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[   34.611461] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   34.611492] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:08:00:0b:26/00:00:3a:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 40/00:0c:00:0b:26/00:00:3a:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[   34.611501] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[   34.611528] ata1: hard resetting link
[   37.883235] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   37.961609] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   37.961675] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   37.961692] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
[   37.961705] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 ASC=0x21 ASCQ=0x4 
[   37.961721] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 3a 26 0b 00 00 00 08 00
[   37.961733] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 975571712 flags 80700
...
[  419.354379] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 976768896 flags 80700
[  419.354416] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[  419.354420] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 3a 38 4f 80 00 00 08 00
[  419.354422] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 976768896 flags 0
[  419.354426] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 149744, async page read
[  419.387113] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 149744, async page read
[  419.406920] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 487783424, async page read
[  419.406949] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 487783425, async page read
```

Is there anything else I should try? Is the hard disk dead, or is there something I can still do? Is there any more information needed?

*if this question has to be closed, please direct me to a resource where I can ask*

Comment: If you don't have some kind of fake raid and the disk really is sdb  you are not in a good place and should come to terms with your data being lost. You have a sliver of possibility if you get another disk and can use ddrescue to pull data from the failed/failing disk onto s new disk you can rescue info from, or if you go to a professional recovery service but don't get your hopes up. Hopefully you have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate a full smartmontools report and redirect it into a file. Replace the "X" by your drive letter in question:

smartctl -a /dev/sdX > mysmart.txt

Depending on the age of your machine run alternatively

smartctl -a /dev/hdX > mysmart.txt

Publish the report.
Depending on the result:

2. Try to duplicate the disc using ddrescue. How does ddrescue behave? How fast is it?
   What is transfer speed? Please tell.

If 2. fails, asking a professional data recovery company would be the last choice.